# How does ChaincodeStub.delState impact the ledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a specific question on how `org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeStub.delState(String key)` impacts the ledger.

I understand that data on a blockchain can almost never be deleted, but then there is this `delState` method which according to the documentation [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/release-1.4/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeStub.html#delState(java.lang.String)),

```
Records the specified key to be deleted in the writeset of the transaction proposal.

The key and its value will be deleted from the ledger when the transaction is validated and successfully committed.
```

The ledger as I understand it has two components - the blockchain and the world state. What effect does this operation have on the two components?

Comment: The State value for the corresponding key is erased, and the record remains on the blockchain.

Comment: for example, if you insert a state value of `100` into the `user_myeongkil` key and then execute `DelState`, there is `no value` of `user_myeongkil` key in the `StateDB` that preserves the latest value. In the `blockchain`(data-structure), records containing the value `100` in `user_myeongkil` and the record that the value of `user_myeongkil` has been deleted are chained to blocks.

Comment: @myeongkilkim in that case would it still be possible to read the blockchain file and retrieve any information related to that key?

Comment: Yes. If we look at the results alone, the record in which (key, data) was entered and the record in which (key, data) was deleted remain, and the latest state value is none.

Answer (score 3):

In Hyperledger Fabric, Ledger is divided into two components:

1. Blockchain/Transaction Log (LevelDB)
2. World state (LevelDB/CouchDB)

Blockchain Ledger stores the data in the LevelDB and that is append-only, which means you can only add data to it but cannot delete data from it. Since the blockchain ledger works in append-only mode, it maintains the history of the data. While the World state stores the current state only. With world state, you have a choice between LevelDB and CouchDB.

And when you use **getHistoryForKey()** in the chaincode you get the data from the blockchain ledger not from the world state. But when you use **getState()** in the chaincode, you get the data from the world state.

So even if you delete the data using **delState()** the data will be deleted from the world state but it will be present in the Blockchain Ledger, you can retrieve the data from the blockchain using the **getHistoryForKey()** provided that you know the key using which stored the data.

You will get data like this when you will use **getHistoryForKey()**

```
[
  {
   "TxId" :"1121212d...."
   "Timestamp" :"" ,
   "IsDelete": true
   "Record" : {
     .......
      }
   },
  {
   "TxId" :"2221212d...."
   "Timestamp" :"" ,
   "IsDelete": false
   "Record" : {
     .......
    }
   },
 ]
```